# convert a JSON to a string array in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, angular

I feel like I have quite an easy question but I just don't get to the answer...
I parse the .text() of a response from my server with JSON.parse into JSON.
And i actually can access the values of that JSON with: `this.temp[0].name`.
Now i just want to iterate over that JSON and push the values into a string array. But how can i achieve this?

When i attempt to use `for...of` the compiler wants a string or an array but not a JSON. When i attempt to use `for...in` it actually does not go into the loop.

Here is some code where i can access it fine:

```
       this._pS.getAllProjects()
        .subscribe(data => this.temp = JSON.parse(data.text()),
            err => console.log(err),
            () => console.log("hello " + this.temp[0].name + this.temp[1].name));
```

When i just print it out after .stringify():

```
        this._pS.getAllProjects()
        .subscribe(data => this.temp = JSON.stringify(data),
            err => console.log(err),
            () => console.log("hello " + this.temp));
```

i get this in the browser console:

```
{"_body":"[{\"name\":\"Projekt A\"},{\"name\":\"Projekt XYZ\"}]",
"status":200,
"ok":true,
"statusText":"Ok",
"headers":{"Content-Type":["application/json; charset=utf-8"]},
"type":2,
"url":"http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/getAllProjectNames"}
```

**tl;dr: how can i get the values out of text part of the body into a string array?**

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the response is what you included then it's simple:

```
JSON.parse(data.text()).forEach(item => {
    console.log(item.name);
});
```

As your body is an array of objects of this interface:

```
interface ObjectInResponseArray {
    name: string;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

First off, you're mixing up JSON and objects. JSON is a text format for transferring data. Once you parse it (`JSON.parse`) you've got an object or an array, depending on the contents of the JSON.

```
var json = "{\"key\": \"value\" }";
var object = JSON.parse(json);
json = "[1, 2, \"three\"]";
var array = JSON.parse(json);
```

Next, it looks like you already have an object. If you do `JSON.stringify`, you're converting an object into a string. So you can access your `data` object directly. No need to convert one way or the other.

```
console.log(data._body[0]);
```

Are you familiar with [`for` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)? They're the most common way of iterating through an array in JavaScript (and most languages, actually). For example:

```
var objs = [
  {
    name: 'Bugs'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bunny'
  }
];
for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
  var obj = objs[i];
  console.log(obj.name);
}
```

Given all of that, you should be able to iterate over your `data._body` array and access the `name` property on each element.

Since your question is a bit unclear, it's possible you'll need to iterate over the parsed contents of `data.text()`.

```
var objs = JSON.parse(data.text());
// Use a simple loop like above
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like

```
this._pS.getAllProjects()
        .subscribe(resp => {
                 this.temp = resp.json();
                 console.log("hello " + this.temp[0].name + this.temp[1].name);
            },
            err => console.log(err),
            () => console.log("getAllProjectsDone")
)
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use `map`:

```
this._pS.getAllProjects()
        .map(resp => resp.json())
        .map(json => json.map(project => project.name)).subscribe(...);
```